# What does an originating flight on your itinerary mean?

Tags: air-travel

I booked a flight with United Airlines.
However, some of the flight legs are operated by airline partners of United Airlines.

For example, under one of the flights, it says:

> Flight operated by ANA ALL NIPPON AIRWAYS.
>
> If this is an originating flight on your itinerary, please check in at the ANA ALL NIPPON ticket counter.

What does "originating flight" mean?
Does it mean the first flight on a multi-leg journey?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the first flight of an itinerary.

Evidence:

- [source](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/originating-flight.html) - " First flight of an itinerary, the top most flight listed on a ticket."
- [source](https://thelawdictionary.org/originating-flight/) - "Listed at the top of airline tickets, this is the first flight in an itinerary."
- [source](https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k8754805-What_is_an_originating_flight-Air_Travel.html) - "Your originating flight is your first flight"